# JavaFX XYChart's weird behaviour on replacing all series

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

once again, I scratch my head while working with JavaFX-Charts... :-(

I have a usecase for which I need to replace all series in the chart, I create everything from scratch. When adding after clearing the previous data, the chart assigns the wrong style-classes for *default-color* to *some* of the added series...
More precisely, the assigned class-numbers get shifted... why on earth did they implement that with modulo, which by default limits to only 8 (!) different color-symbol-combinations...?!

The first 8 (hint: mod 8...) default-colors are correct:

```
default-color0
...
default-color7
```

and for the first run, it continues, also correct, again with 0:

```
default-color0
...
default-color6 (for 15 series in my example)
```

for the second run, I get:

```
default-color0
...
default-color7
default-color7 <-- shift from here
default-color0
...
default-color5
```

as you can see, the it is shifted, having two times 7 and then only running until 5.
For another run, the shift continues:

```
default-color0
...
default-color7
default-color6 <-- shift from here
default-color7
default-color0
...
default-color4
```

the amount of shifting is dependent on the number of series - for 16, everything is fine, for 14, it shifts 2 each time and so on.

In the chart this is nicely visible if you watch the legend changing...

I tried different methods of replacing the data, but none of them was successful, see comments in the code below.
An actual solution, but in my eyes not a very pretty one, is to manually overwrite the style-class, which isn't that easy as well, because of the aggressive habits of the task-class... wtf?!

whatever - if anyone has any helpful idea on that? maybe I'm missing something?

**Note:** To see the weired results, remove the lines marked as *DIRTY-WORKAROUND-SOLUTION*. Otherwise it would work... ;-)

Bonus-Question: maybe I'm silly, working with that JavaFX-Charts... some things are cool, but often times, I have a weired feeling about it... are there better alternatives you would recommend me to checo out?

Thanks!

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ChartSeriesReplacing extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        VBox root = new VBox();

        ScatterChart<Number, Number> chart = new ScatterChart<>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());

        Button refresh = new Button("Refresh");

        refresh.setOnAction(clicked -> {
            List<XYChart.Series<Number, Number>> seriesList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
                series.setName(i + "");

                XYChart.Data<Number, Number> data = new XYChart.Data<>(Math.random(), Math.random());
                int finalI = i;
                data.nodeProperty().addListener(__ -> {
                    if (data.getNode() != null) {
                        data.getNode().getStyleClass().addListener((InvalidationListener) ___ -> {

                            System.out.println("[pre] Data #" + finalI + ": Style = " + data.getNode().getStyleClass());

                            // DIRTY-WORKAROUND-SOLUTION:
                            // (has to live in listener, otherwise the chart erases any custom styling on adding... :-/ )
                            String colorString = "default-color" + finalI % 8;
                            data.getNode().getStyleClass().removeIf(s -> s.startsWith("default-color") && !s.equals(colorString));
                            if (!data.getNode().getStyleClass().contains(colorString)) {
                                data.getNode().getStyleClass().add(colorString);
                            }
                            // --------------------------

                            System.out.println("[post] Data #" + finalI + ": Style = " + data.getNode().getStyleClass());
                        });
                    }
                });
                series.getData().add(data);

                seriesList.add(series);
            }
            System.out.println("-----------------");

            // What I tried:
            // 1)
            chart.getData().setAll(seriesList);

            // 2)
            // chart.dataProperty().setValue(FXCollections.observableArrayList(seriesList));

            // 3)
            // chart.getData().clear();
            // 3a)
            // chart.getData().addAll(seriesList);
            // 3b)
            // seriesList.forEach(series->chart.getData().add(series));
        });


        root.getChildren().add(chart);
        root.getChildren().add(refresh);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Java-Version jdk1.8.0_171 (x64)

Comment: good that you (at least I assume it was you :) reported the bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8209778